# Unable to get the read only text box value on reactive form

Tags: angular, reactive

I have a `read-only text input (3)` as shown below.

[image]

**.ts**

```
wokeUpTime: number = 0;

constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, ) {
    this.sleepingDetailsForm = formBuilder.group({
      wokeUpTime: [0],
     });
  }

save(data): void {
  if (this.sleepingDetailsForm.valid) {
  //save
 }
}
```

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="sleepingDetailsForm" (submit)="save(sleepingDetailsForm)" novalidate>
     <h3 color="primary">Woke up time?</h3>
     <div class="wokeuptime">
       <button type="button" (click)="decreaseWokeupTime()">-</button>
        <input type="text" [readonly]="true" value={{wokeUpTime}} formControlName="wokeUpTime">
       <button type="button" (click)="increaseWokeupTime()">+</button>
    </div>
 <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!sleepingDetailsForm.valid">Save</button>
```

The question here is, I cannot get the value of read-only text input through `wokeUpTime`.Here I'm using reactive form approach.I know this is happening due to I'm not typing anything in the text box.But what is the workaround for this? I need to get the values through form variable `this.sleepingDetailsForm`.How can I do that? I know I can get the value directly from the `this.wokeUpTime` inside the `save()` method since it is a global variable. But how can I get it from the `form` itself?

Comment: Please create a live example on: www.plnkr.co

Comment: I edited my post in case you missed it... use one-way-binding if you are increasing and decreasing `wokeUpTime` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Or even better, if you are working with `wokeUpTime`, you can use one-way-binding, and the form control will get the value set:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="wokeUpTime" [readonly]="true" 
        formControlName="wokeUpTime">
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

However you increase or decrease, you need to set the value to the form control when you do that.

so it should be:

```
this.sleepingDetailsForm.get('wokeUpTime').patchValue(...the new value here...)
```

then your value will be part of the form values.

Comment: Excellent.Thank you very much, friend :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Have a nice day and haaaaappy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to bind `value` if you're using reactive forms. You can get the current state of your form group from your code using `this.sleepingDetailsForm.value` - therefore, getting the value of your field is as simple as `this.sleepingDetailsForm.value.wokeUpTime`.

Comment: No.I have removed value and tried that.Same behavior.That is due to I'm not typing anything on the text box.If I type something on it, then it works nicely. What is the workaround for this? I need to show the value dynamically when user inc/dec value.

Comment: @Sampath, why don't you use <input type="number" min="1" max="5" onchange="alert('value changed')" name="quantity" > ?